# $g((x_n))= (\frac{x_n}{n})$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Define $g:\ell_2 \to \ell_1$ by $g((x_n))= (\frac{x_n}{n})$. Show that
>   $g$ is uniformly continuous.

Although, the question describes $g((x_n))= (\frac{x_n}{n}).$

But we basically have, if $x=(x_n)\in \ell_2$ then,

$g(x)= (\frac{x_n}{n})$

Note that for $x=(x_n)$ and $y=(y_n) $ both in $\ell_2$

$$|| g(x)-g(y)||_1 = ||(\frac{x_n}{n}) - (\frac{y_n}{n})||_1 =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |\frac{x_{n}^{k}}{k} - \frac{x_n^k}{k} | =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}| x_n^k - y_n^k | \cdot |\frac1k| =$$

$$ =|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(| x_n^k - y_n^k | \cdot |\frac1k|)| \leq^{(\text{Cauchy Schwartz ineq})} ||x-y||_2\cdot||\frac1n||_2 \to 0\; \text{as} \;||x-y||_2 \to 0 \; \text{because} \; ||\frac1n||_2 < \infty\; \text{since}\; (\frac1n) \in \ell_2$$

Is this proof ok?

Comment: Yes, it is ok. You could also prove that $g$ is a bounded linear map and thus $\|g(x)-g(y)\|_1  = \|g(x-y)\|_1\le\|g\|\|x-y\|_2$.